# Is there a way to "import" from other on-disk Java projects in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have two Java Projects in Eclipse, and I'd like to make one be able to access the classes in the other, without making it difficult to tell which classes came from which -- or, ideally, without having to list the classes in the accessing project. In other words, it looks like this (but with many more files):

Proj01

    [package]

        Useful.java

Proj02

    [package]

        CurrentProject.java

And I want to have some sort of equivalent of "import Proj01.Useful;" in CurrentProject.java. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the project as a dependency to the other.

Rightclick project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Projects Tab -> Add... -> Select the other project -> Click Ok.

You should now be able to import classes from the other project.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you want to do is package 'Proj01' as a JAR file and include that JAR as a dependency in 'Proj02'. This will allow you to import the required class(es) in Proj02.

Personally, I'd recommend checking out [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Maven helps manage dependencies in your project and also the build process (which in your case can be used for building the necessary JAR file[s]).

Alternatively, if you're using a tool like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), you can use it to [package up a JAR](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm) of your project.